# Make RandomizedSearchCV() faster

Tags: python, optimization, parameters, random-forest

I have a data frame like this but bigger.

```
            JAN                 Feb            
            PRICE AMOUNT NAME   PRICE AMOUNT NAME
 2011-03-31     2      7    3       6      0    5
 2011-04-01     6      2    5       0      4    2
 2011-04-04     9      0    7       2      7    9
 2011-04-05     5      3    5       7      9    9
```

I'm trying to apply the random forest model and, to find the best parameters, I apply this code that I find on this link: https://medium.com/@maryamuzakariya/project-predict-stock-prices-using-random-forest-regression-model-in-python-fbe4edf01664

```
model = RandomForestRegressor() 
grid_rf = {
    'n_estimators': [500],  
    'max_depth': [5,10,15,20,25,30],  
    'min_samples_split': [2,5,10,15,20,25,30], 
    'min_samples_leaf': [1,5,10,15,20,25,30]
}
rscv = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=model, param_distributions=grid_rf, cv=3, n_jobs=-1, verbose=2, n_iter=200)
rscv_fit = rscv.fit(x_train, y_train)
best_parameters = rscv_fit.best_params_
print(best_parameters)
```

All the input in grid_rf and recv are chosen and must remain the same.
When I run it I get a lot of warning saying:

```
FutureWarning: Feature names only support names that are all strings. Got feature names with dtypes: ['tuple']. An error will be raised in 1.2. warnings.warn(
```

Warnings are not a problem because, In the end, it works.
My problem is that it is very slow. Is there any way to make it faster?

Thank you in advice

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And please [edit] your question to be more specific about your problem and what you're actually ask about. Don't combine multiple different problems into a single question.

Comment: Also please be careful when selecting tags for your question. Properly selected tags will attract the right audience to your question, but a bad selection will just make people downvote your questions. For example what are the `parameters` and `portfolio` tags doing for this question? How are they relevant (reading their descriptions)? And if you're programming in a specific language, and want answers in that language, then prioritize the tag of that language over other less relevant tags. If you want a true algorithm-related answer without regards to language, use the `language-agnostic` tag.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have modified the question in order to make it more specific; I also change the tags like you said.

Comment: The tags 'parameters' and 'portfolio' were added because the function in the script is to find the best parameters for the random forest model that I am using to build a portfolio. I thought that people that will have the same problem can, in the future, find a solution.